# Matlab error with fzero, method isfinite is undefined

Tags: matlab

I just want to find a zero for the hypergeometric function

```
g = @(x) hypergeom((1-x)./2,1,1)

fzero(g,15)
??? Undefined function or method 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Error in ==> fzero at 333
    elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)
```

This same instructions were working before!!
What happened?? 
What can I do??

Comment: That is weird, it works for me.  What version of MATLAB?  Also, do you have Symbolic Math Toolbox installed?  It won't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be caused by several things:

1. You may not have the Symbolic Toolbox. Be sure you installed it with the license when you do a proper install of MATLAB. Remember that for a lot of toolbox functionality simply copying in the toolbox from another source may not work (also, see licensing below).
2. Your path may be reordered or corrupted in a way that prevents MATLAB from finding this function. Reset your path to the original by selecting File->SetPath from the pulldown menu and then click the *Default* button on the bottom. Click the *Save* and try your code again.
3. Your isfinite function has accidentally been deleted. I would recommend just reinstalling MATLAB.
4. You license does not include Symbolic toolbox *or* your license file is corrupted. If you don't have a proper license, MATLAB will make a little effort to handicap your MATLAB experience. If you are sure you do have a license look in the toolbox folder of MATLAB and be sure you have a folder (with files in it!) named *symbolic* (probably something like 
   "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\symbolic"). You may take a look at your environment variable LM_LICENSE_FILE and check your MATLAB license file in your matlab/license directory and see if there is anything missing (the license.dat file, say) or strange (empty file, etc). A reinstall might also help this. Mathworks support may be able to help you here.
5. Multiple installs might hurt. You may have trouble if you have multiple versions of MATLAB installed with and without symbolic toolbox. Licenses may collide and you may try uninstalling everything and just picking your favorite.